# Exporting Multiple Sizes for Print - Automation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, automation

I have loads of images i need to solve the following problem with.

Each image is a unique size, I need to export each of them for print at a couple different page sizes. e.g: A1, A2, 3inch x 5 inch etc.

Is there a way to do this automatically or with a batch process?

I am struggling with the fact they are all different size source images. Currently i am doing it by creating the different artboard sizes in Illustrator with a mask and linked file. I replace the linked file each time but need to manually resize.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Ho would any automation know *where* to crop an image? Or how to "resize" without degrading the image?

Comment: Yes this is the part I am wanting to see if possible. The images are high enough resolution to fit any of the canvas sizes. If there was a way to make the shortest part of the image fit the canvas, then centre align the longest part (this will bleed off).

I can't find an answer to this and not sure there is a capability, but wanted to see if anyone else has a solution.

Comment: Well there are algirithms that can try to find points of interest. But then photoshop does not seem like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two ways of doing it properly:

**i) With Manual Control over cropping etc**:

1. Load the Images at once in Photoshop
2. Crop non destructively and manually
3. Export the layers at once

*Detailed Method:* [PhotoshopCafe Link](https://photoshopcafe.com/automating-photoshop-crop-reposition-multiple-photographs/)

**ii) With an External Tool without any Manual intervention:**

Since cropping also requires some understanding of which part of image to crop and which not to, Photoshop might not be suitable. There are other tools which might help you do the job:

[BRIME](https://www.birme.net/)   [BatchCrop](https://www.batchcrop.com/index.php)

**Related Question**: 
[Question Link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4949/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-crop-bulk-images?rq=1)

*Note:*
*You might already know this but I will add that if you're using photoshop, you will need to use CMYK at 150%-300 dpi as settings.
If you're using external tools, you will need to convert dimensions of the image to fit that dpi, process the images using external tool and then batch convert color and dpi for print using photoshop.*